# (options) should be type Object, but it was type number with value 2

Tags: goinstant, goangular

I am getting a strange error when attempting to use the $goQuery feature.  Here is my code:

```
 var options = "{sort: null, limit: null}";
 var expr = "{userName: 'asdf'}";
 $scope.person = $goQuery('person',expr, options).$sync();
```

I'm getting the following error message:

[Link to Error Message Image](http://screencast.com/t/jq0cqJV9)

I tried converting the vars to JSON.parse objects, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work. I tried the object direct versus the string:

```
$scope.person = $goQuery('person', { userName: $scope.person.findme }, { sort: { 'userName': 'asc' }, limit: 1 }).$sync();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the string literals, you need to pass the Objects themselves.  In addition to this, you need to supply valid values for `sort` and `limit`.  For example, using the code you posted:

```
var options = { sort: { 'userName': 'asc' }, limit: 5 };
var expr = {userName: 'asdf'};
$scope.person = $goQuery('person',expr, options).$sync();
```